# jqueryui opening multiple dialogs; should only open one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a feed with comments and want to allow users to delete a comment. The code below allows users to click on an image and a dialog box appears that alerts users of the deletion.

Right now, this applies to every comment on the page, so that clicking the delete button once opens up multiple dialogs (as many dialogs as there are comments).

How can I alter the code below so that when the selector is clicked, only the dialog box for that comment appears?

```
$('span.delete_comment_button img').click(function() { 
        $('.delete_comment_dialog').dialog('open'); 
        return false; 
});
```

Comment: Why dont you just have one dialog box or create the dialog box on the fly? It could improve the load time of the page since you wont have to create the dialog on each of the dialog boxes. If this is not a suitable option, please show us your html so we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should not have multiple `#delete_comment_dialog` elements on the page so we'll change that to `.delete_comment_dialog`. Then you can add a class to the comment as a whole, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up to the top level comment wrapper, and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to come back down to the dialog. The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="comment">
    blah blah blah blah
    <span class="delete_comment_button">delete</span>
    <div class="delete_comment_dialog">first dialog</div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
    blah blah blah blah
    <span class="delete_comment_button">delete</span>
    <div class="delete_comment_dialog">second dialog</div>
</div>​
```

And your jQuery like this:

```
$('span.delete_comment_button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.comment')
           .find('.delete_comment_dialog')
           .dialog('open');
    return false; 
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/VePZp/

Alternatively, use a single dialog with an `id` attribute, add `id`s to your comment `<div>`s, and pass the `id` of the comment to delete through a `data` attribute or similar. For example:

```
<div id="cmt1" class="comment">
    blah blah blah blah
    <span class="delete_comment_button">delete</span>
</div>
<div id="cmt2" class="comment">
    blah blah blah blah
    <span class="delete_comment_button">delete</span>
</div>
<div id="delete_comment_dialog">the only dialog</div>
```

And:

```
$('#delete_comment_dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    close: function() {
        // 'close' handler just for demonstration purposes.
        alert($('#delete_comment_dialog').data('kill-this'));
    }
});
$('span.delete_comment_button').click(function() {
    var $cmt = $(this).closest('.comment');
    $('#delete_comment_dialog').data('kill-this', $cmt[0].id);
    $('#delete_comment_dialog').dialog('open');
    return false; 
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/M4QM6/​

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer; this has everything I need!

Answer (score 1):

You can also give you each image and dialog a specific ID so that you can better target each one. Since you are looping through your comments already you can just append the index of the loop, otherwise you can use a random number:

```
<span class="delete_comment_button"><img id="1" /></span>
<div id="delete_comment_dialog1"></div>
```

Your jquery would then be

```
$('span.delete_comment_button img').click(function() { 
        $('#delete_comment_dialog' + THIS.ID).dialog('open'); 
        return false; 
});
```

Ideally you would want to use something other than ID for the index storage as ID's shouldn't contain only numbers.

You might also be able to use the $.each function with return false. If you include return false in the $.each loop it should stop after 1 iteration and only open 1 dialog.